# Generic Class and List edit key and value

Tags: c#

I would like to create a generic list which takes in a generic class. But the problem is i can't access the variables inside the generic class and i've seen people leave the interface empty and wonder how i should do to access the variables in the class.

```
public List<IAttributeInterface> attributes = new List<IAttributeInterface>();
public void AddAttribute<T>(T attribute, T value)
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (attributes[i].key == attribute)
        {
            attributes[i].value = value;
            return;
        }
    }

    attributes.Add(new Attribute(attribute, value));
}

public class Attribute<T> where T : IAttributeInterface
{
    public T key;
    public T value;

    public Attribute(T key, T value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public interface IAttributeInterface
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to add properties inside of interfaces:

```
public interface IAttributeInterface<T>
{
    T Key { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then we need to implement this generic interface in class to be able to create instance of object:

```
public class Attribute<T> : IAttributeInterface<T>
{   
    public T Key { get; set ; }
    public T Value { get ; set; }

    public Attribute(T key, T value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

and your method will look like this:

```
public List<IAttributeInterface<string>> attributes = 
    new List<IAttributeInterface<string>>();

public void AddAttribute<T>(T attribute, T value) where T: IAttributeInterface<string>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (attributes[i].Key == attribute.Key)
        {
            attributes[i].Value = value.Value;
            return;
        }
     }
     attributes.Add(new Attribute<string>("key", "value"));
}
```

and it is possible to use like that:

```
AddAttribute(new Attribute<string>("foo key 0", "foo value 0"), 
    new Attribute<string>("foo key 1", "foo value 1"));
```

Comment: should be `where T : IAttributeInterface<string>` just to make it more general?

Comment: @0xDECAFBAD yeah, you are right! Thanks for the awesome comment! I've updated reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add {get;set;} for those attributes (properties) in the interface.

```
public interface IAttributeInterface<T>
{
    T Key { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ´Can you please provide an example?